# Remove the [c2x] tag and replace it with [c23]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Posting this mostly for the record since I can fix this myself.

There are 8 questions tagged [c2x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c2x), used for the upcoming C language standard. Since the tag was created, this upcoming standard has been informally named [c23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c23) and we have a tag like that too. They mean the same thing. They shouldn't be made synonymous since "C2x" is a placeholder name (and there might be yet another C draft before 2030 also to be called "C2x" for all we know).

I'm going to go ahead and remove all [c2x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c2x) tags and replace them with [c23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c23). I'll give it a couple of days here on meta before I go ahead with the "simple burnination" procedure.

Comment: I [a moderator] can actually do this for you by merging one tag into another without creating a synonym. It's one click, as opposed to dozens for you. (The only advantage of the manual way would be if the existing 8 questions need editing/cleanup anyway.) I'll leave it a few days to make sure there are no objections before pulling the trigger.

Comment: @CodyGray Oh, well that sounds handy. No biggie in this case but perhaps less distruptive. Will the mod merger "bump" all posts like manual edits would? If it doesn't, then that's preferable I think.

Comment: No, no bumping. Tag merges leave no trace in the revision history whatsoever.

Comment: Leads to a side question: What about questions about rules/features in the proposed standard that don't make it to, or are substantively changed on route to, the formal Standard revision? What should they be tagged as? Still tag as C23 and leave a big caveat in the question and answers marking the behaviour as obsoleted?

Comment: @user4581301 If they don't make it into C23 I would not tag them as C23 because they are not part of it. If they are added but the implementation as changed since asking, a comment, or a notice edited into the question, is probably sufficient along with the C23 tag.

Comment: @TylerH That's my thinking. After that Standard is finalized, a new question's either about C23 or it isn't. I'm concerned with questions asked during the Standardization process and then orphaned by a rule change or feature drop between the asking of the question and the release of the Standard.

Comment: @user4581301 Does C or Stack Overflow in general have any other precedent for tags about proposed-then-abandoned language features? Something like [tag:proposed-features] or something? Best I can find is [tag:language-features], which isn't really ideal.

Comment: @TylerH I mostly follow C++ and have seen questions about proposed features that vanished from C++11, but the Stack Overflow universe was very different back then. I've probably seen questions about changes in C++17 and 20, but when they went up and have no idea how they were handled in the aftermath. It's very possible I'm just chasing an issue with zero impact.

Comment: @user4581301 My gut tells me we don't need to keep such questions tagged with a specific language version tag when they aren't in that language once it's released... just the general language tag and the context of the question is probably enough. Especially if it isn't something that occurs often (though I'm sure it occurs more often in C and C++ than many other language tags...)

Comment: I think this retagging is premature.  Wait until the standard is actually standard — published.  C17 got published in 2018.  C89 wasn't standardized by ISO until 1990.  Wait until it is finalized before making this change.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: We still don't want 2 separate tags for the same thing until then, though.  Unlike new C++ standards, there probably won't be a lot of new questions about C23 stuff even as the date approaches, but still best to at least synonymize the tags if not merge.  Or ban the [c23] tag until C23 is an official ISO standard?  But it's now been unofficially named that.

Comment: "(and there might be yet another C draft before 2030 also to be called "C2x" for all we know)" I thought the next one will be "C2y" if it's this decade, for the exact reason of avoiding that ambiguity.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler We don't 2 tags for the same thing. It's easier to fix things now when there aren't many questions yet. If it gets released in 2024, well we can rename the merged tag then.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Far as I recall, both C11 and C17 were initially called C1x.

Comment: @CodyGray This has been sitting on meta for a week and was even HNQ briefly, so I'd say it has been sufficiently advertised. Since no major objections was raised, perhaps we can go ahead and do the merge you proposed? Otherwise I can edit everything manually too, no problem, but that's more intrusive in terms of "bumping".

Comment: I went ahead and fixed it myself. If someone wants to smack a status-completed sticker on the question, please do.

Comment: Sorry, I've been busy lately, and my inbox overflows on a daily basis, so I missed getting back to this. Thanks for handling it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has been sitting on meta for a week and was even featured as "hot" for a while. Since there were no major objections, I have now cleared up all questions tagged [c2x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c2x) and replaced it with [c23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c23) where appropriate.

I added this message to the C2x tag wiki:

> DO NOT USE! The tag is obsolete, use C23 instead.

For the record, the merge moderator procedure proposed by @CodyGray in the comments seems smoother and less intrusive, but since this was just 8 questions, I went ahead and fixed it myself.